# How can I declare same object name for different class?

Tags: c++, class, object

Normally this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class On {
    public:
    int value;
};

class Off {
    public:
    int value;
};


int main() {
    On push;
    push.value = 1;
    cout << push.value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is added two classes named On, Off. I want to create the same object name for both classes that something like below. I know the code is wrong but it's for the example of what I'm expecting.

```
// Full source shown above code
int main() {
    
    On push; // 'push' object for the class -> On
    push.value = 1;
    cout << push.value << endl;

    Off push; // 'push' object for the class -> Off
    push.value = 0;
    cout << push.value << endl; 
    // Here's the problem. How can I can define it's coming from an specific/defferent object?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: why do you want to do this? You won't be able to tell the difference between `push` and `push`, so why do you want them to be two objects?

Comment: Name shadowing is almost always a bug nest, cannot recommend.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasSablik your code worked for me. 
Actually, it's not necessary. I'm just thinking if I need like this anywhere else then how should I write this code. That's why asked the question. Thanks to all of you for providing suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scopes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class On {
    public:
    int value;
};

class Off {
    public:
    int value;
};


int main() {
    {
        On push; // 'push' object for the class -> On
        push.value = 1;
        cout << push.value << endl;
    }
    {
        Off push; // 'push' object for the class -> Off
        push.value = 0;
        cout << push.value << endl; 
        // Here's the problem. How can I can define it's coming from an specific/defferent object?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put every one in different namespace :

```
namespace N1 { On push; }
namespace N2 { On push; }
```

usage :

```
 N1::push.value
 N2::push.value
```

Comment: Thank you @ouchane, your code is also worked. BTW, in your code namespace N2 should be { Off push; }

Comment: yeah you can use any other type you want :)